# Clearing all prefixes

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I have several prefixes in play in an existing CakePHP app. I also have a bit of primary navigation in the layout that points to shared methods. I know I can explicitly set each prefix to false to avoid linking with the prefix, but is there a shortcut path that simply tells Cake to no use any prefixes no matter which one's context may currently exist?

For example, I'm on a page where a realtor can register (`/realtor/users/register`). I have a similar prefix for inspectors and contractors because the registration process is slightly different. Since I'm not authenticated, there's a *Login* link in the primary nav, but the login action is shared by all user types and should be accessed without any prefix.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link( 'Login', array( 'controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login', 'realtor' => false, 'inspector' => false, 'contractor' => false ) ) ?>
```

I'd like to be able to, in the link, just turn off all prefixing rather than turning off each possible prefix independently. Possible?

Comment: possible with a helper method. do you use Configure::write('Routing.prefixes') to define them?

Comment: Yes, the prefixes are defined using routing.prefixes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If loosing the routing capabilities is not a problem for you, you could pass a string instead of an array to the link() method:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Html->link('Login', '/users/login');
?>
```

**EDIT**

To keep routing mechanism, here is a little Helper that would do the trick:

```
class MyHtmlHelper extends HtmlHelper
{
    public function link($title, $url = null, $options = array(), $confirmMessage = false)
    {
        $prefixes = Router::prefixes();

        foreach($prefixes as $prefix)
        {
            $url[$prefix] = false;
        }

        return parent::link($title, $url, $options, $confirmMessage);
    }
}
```

Off course you could change the method name if you want to keep the standard link() method. I tested this with Cake2, but this should work with Cake1.3

Comment: Yeah, I'd really rather not lose routing.

Comment: OK, I edited my answer with an example helper that would maybe suit your needs

Comment: I do somethink similar. your solution looks even shorter and easier i have to admit. tip: call it defaultLink() - thats what i called mine

Comment: Nice. I thought there might be an existing API, but your helper looks tight. Much appreciated.

Comment: Just a note. I think this will override existing $url[$prefix] that where set to true. That can be easily worked around.

Answer (score 4):

I know it's been 2 years since the question above was answered, though I think I found an even less intrusive way to accomplish what you want.
Set the prefix name dynamically by taking the current prefix value from `$this->params` and set it to `false`, like so

```
$this->Html->link('hello', array($this->params['prefix']=>false, 'controller'=>'posts','action'=>'index'));
```

The value of `$this->params['prefix']` will be the one and relevant at that moment to set to `false`.

cheers