# CakePHP Plugin affecting default routes

Tags: cakephp, plugins, routes

I just created a plugin named `ContactForm`

Now on the default layout have the following links:

```
$this->Html->link('Home', array('controller' => 'posts', 'action' => 'index','admin' => false));
$this->Html->link('About', array('controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'display', 'about', 'admin' => false))
```

The Plugin works fine. My problem is when I am going to `/contact_form/contacts/add`, all links on the page appends the plugin url, which makes the following links:

`/posts/index` into `/contact_form/posts/index`
`/pages/about` into `/contact_form/pages/about`

I know you can add `'plugin' => null` to all links on the main application, but is there a way to work things out from the plugin itself?

Comment: You have to set 'plugin'=>false to otherwise you will remain inside the plugin routing.

Comment: One way would be to create an Helper that overrides the link() method. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014296/clearing-all-prefixes/8022386

Comment: @timstermatic, I figured that out by using `'plugin' => null`. My question is how do I not do this and do it from the Plugin? Is there a way?